# Can't configure Microsoft Comfort 4500 mouse on Mac

Tags: macos, mouse

I purchased a Microsoft Comfort 4500 mouse for my Mac (MBP running Sierra) and I also installed the Microsoft Mouse config for the System Preferences.
[image]

There are two things that I am unable to configure:

1. The pointer speed doesn't change, in spite of me going into the Pointer Options section, selecting Intellipoint pointer speed, and moving it from Slow to Fast. No change in either direction.
   [image]
2. I'm unable to configure the side buttons. Both right and left buttons appear to open links in a new tab (when used in a browser), even when the config appears to indicate that they should be Back and Forward.
   [image]
3. I don't even see when I can configure the side button of the scroll wheel, which currently doesn't do anything.

In case this is relevant, in the "normal" mouse section of the System Preferences, the mouse isn't detected at all. It does appear in the System Profile.

[image]

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with High Sierra. But I mean the problem is the official driver (available: https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-gb/business/comfort-mouse-4500-for-business/4eh-00002) is compatible with Mac OS 10.4 — 10.7 only but not with the laters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get the old Microsoft Intellipointer Mice working on newer versions of MacOS due to security:

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-12241

In the end of the article it says you CAN make them work by disabling system integrity protection, but that doesn't seem quite worth it.